# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mle2 de R ajuste una ecuación a partir de datos propios?

Tags: r, matemáticas

He tenido problemas para hacer un ajuste de una ecuación en *R* empleando en paquete `bbmle`, y usando una ecuación personalizada (con dos exponenciales). He tratado de hacerlo de diferentes formas pero no he podido lograr que la ecuación se ajuste a los datos (empleo dicha paqueteria porque trato de ajustarlo a partir de máxima verosimilitud)

El código que empleo es el siguiente:

```
library(bbmle)
library(stats4)

x = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 2.6, 2.8, 3, 3.2, 
      3.4, 3.6, 3.8, 4, 4.2, 4.4, 4.6, 4.8, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.6, 5.8, 6, 6.2, 6.4,
      6.6, 6.8, 7, 7.2, 7.4, 7.6, 7.8, 8, 8.2, 8.4, 8.6, 8.8, 9)

y = c(1, 0.54099275, 0.187395427, 0.126603458, 0.109313999, 0.102063581, 0.093697713,
      0.090909091, 0.088120468, 0.085331846, 0.081985499, 0.081427775, 0.080312326,
      0.079196877, 0.078081428, 0.077523703, 0.07585053, 0.075292805, 0.071388734,
      0.070831009, 0.069715561, 0.068042387, 0.065253765, 0.063022867, 0.059118795,
      0.055214724, 0.052426102, 0.047964306, 0.04350251, 0.039598438, 0.036252091,
      0.034578918, 0.030674847, 0.028443949, 0.025655326, 0.022308979, 0.020635806,
      0.018404908, 0.017289459, 0.013943112, 0.012269939, 0.01115449,
      0.010596765, 0.010039041, 0.008365867)

mle2(y ~ p*w*exp(-w*(x-d)) + (1-p)*b*exp(-b*(x-d)),
     start = c(p = 0.7, w = 3, b = 0.2, d = 0.2),
     data = list(x = x, y = y),
     parnames = c("p", "w", "b", "d"))
```

Una vez que empleo el código me aparece el siguiente error:

> Error in -w : invalid argument to unary operator

Posteriormente, traté de hacer lo mismo con las funciones que *R* tiene por defecto (en este caso la `dexp`), empleando el siguiente código:

```
mle2(y ~ p*dexp(x - d, rate = lambda1) + (1-p)*dexp(x - d, rate = lambda2),
     data = list(df),
     start = list(p = 0.7, lambda1 = 2, lambda2 = 0.5, d = 0.2))
```

Al ejecutar el codigo, me aparece lo siguiente:

> Error in `+`(x = c(1, 0.54099275, 0.187395427, 0.126603458, 0.109313999, :
>   operator needs one or two arguments

¿Cómo soluciono este problema?